# how to handle after Certificate Expiry or Renew

Tags: corda

This is different block-chain data level from tradition web application.I generated self-signed ca certification and client nodes could communicate with each other after signed. so I have below questions:

- how to process if ca certification expiry?
- if ca certification didn't expiry how to process client certification
  expiry?
- if both didn't    expiry how to process certification encrypt for
  revocation like    changed algorithm?

if from own node, I can re-import data after renew cert. how about client node?

Answer (score 0):

Corda is agnostic on this. It is up to the certificate authority. They decide whether certificates expire and how they revoke certificates.

If you choose to have a system where certificates expire, you need to also provide your own mechanism for provisioning the new certificates to the nodes. The nodes then need to update the keystores in their `<workspace>/certificates/` folders accordingly (see https://docs.corda.net/permissioning.html).

Comment: Hi Joel, singer need sign txid + sign's metadata. maybe you said that be helpful for client certification expiry.